# Calculating percentage total of scaled survey data

Tags: python, data-cleaning, percentage, calculation

I have a csv file which has survey data with target variable "Answer".

The variable "Answer" has scaled data points ranging from 0-100. I want to have two columns one with "Answer" and the other with "grand total count %". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9naq.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)